# How to configure "Same as Display" as processing extent by default in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, geoprocessing, tools, extents

I'm working on a very simple model for creating a path from a selected point to the closest polyline, in this model I used a Cost Distance and Cost Path tool for creating the more feasible track (considering the slope).

Everything works fine, but because I'm using a Cost Raster from a very large area (whole México country) the processing is very slow, so I set the processing extent as "Same as Display", the problem comes when I select another point from a different extent, the processing extent have to be configured in the model as "Same as Display" other way it is automatically set as "As Specified Below"

[image]

What I want to know is if there is a way to configure the Processing Extent as "Same As Display" and it stay like that as default doesn't matter where I select the point. I want this model to be published on web but I don't want to add the processing extent as parameter

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. Setting the environment to 'same as display' will use the extent of the ArcMap window... whatever it is at the time of the beginning of the execution of this tool. This setting has no meaning in ArcCatalog of course. Perhaps your slow execution has to do with extracting the extent of the big raster into a temporary storage location; poor performance of web tools can be difficult to diagnose. What format is the big raster and is it compressed?